# How to make Trello notification of due dates work

Tags: trello, notifications

I'm using Trello for only myself (my team is not interested). But I've found it useful as a task list just for me. I would like to receive a notification for cards that are due. I've tried subscribing to the card, but I don't seem to receive a notification in the web view or iOS app when it becomes due.

Of course, I can see the due date become RED in the card via the web view. But for those times when I am not at the computer, I'd like the notification to pop up on my iOS app automatically.

Is this possible?